# Clase interna Compare de "Comparator" Java

Tags: java, clase, collection

Para un determinado proyecto tengo que ordenar unas figuras por área y nombre. Primero se ordenan por área de mayor a menor y en caso de coincidir, se ordenan alfabéticamente.
En una clase llamada `RegionRectangular` tengo una clase interna del siguiente tipo:

```
//Clase interna
public class RegionRectangularComparator implements Comparator<RegionRectangular>{
    @Override
    public int compare(RegionRectangular o1, RegionRectangular o2) {
        //devuelve un entero positivo si el area de o1 es mayor que la de o2 [queremos que o1 vaya delante de o2 (o1 < o2)], un negativo si o1 es menor que o2 y 0 se son iguales, entonce ordenaremos por nombre de A a Z
        if ((o1.Area() - o2.Area()) != 0){
            return o1.Area() - o2.Area();   
        }
        return o1.nombre.compareTo(o2.nombre);
    }
}
```

Cómo debo hacer si desde otra clase quiero ordenar un conjunto de `RegionRectangular`?
Pensé que la mejor manera sería la siguiente, pero falla:

```
public void ordenarRegionesXAreaAsc(){
    Collections.sort(regiones, new RegionRectangular.RegionRectangularComparator());
}
```

Donde `private Collection<RegionRectangular> regiones = new ArrayList<>();`

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: *Pero falla* -> Intenta darnos alguna pista más por favor. Como qué es lo que falla? Qué error da?? Nuestras cabezas *todavía* no ejecutan Java al leerlo, así que necesitamos algún detalle que nos permita saber qué podría estar pasando.

Comment: @Benito-B perdona. The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<RegionRectangular>, RegionRectangular.RegionRectangularComparator)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando declaras una clase interna, hay dos opciones, que sea estática o que no lo sea. Si la clase no es estática, es como un método de instancia: **No se puede usar si no es dentro de un objeto** de la clase que lo contiene:

```
class A {

   class Interna {

   }

   void metodoNoEstatico() {
       Interna i = new Interna();
   }

   static void metodoEstatico() {
       Interna i = new Interna(); //NO COMPILA
   }
}
```

Por supuesto, no se puede usar fuera de la clase A, a menos que crees primero una instancia:

```
A objA= new A();
Interna i = objA.new Interna();
```

Si la clase es estática, se puede usar en cualquier sitio:

```
class Parent {
    static class Child {
    }
}

Parent.Child child = new Parent.Child();
```